# Should we really attach the "desktop-client" tag to all questions for desktop use?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just stumbled upon this in our review queue:

[image]

Is it really useful/necessary to point this out for every question? Don't the other tags make the issue clear? Or is this a good thing for filtering by tags ("Well, I need a desktop-client for icons" – huh?)?

Comment: Actually offline tool doesn't mean a desktop client. Offline tool is relevant for mobile app, whereas desktop client is more a laptop or PC requirement... So I think they should be distinguished.

Comment: I don't think this tag should be used much, maybe not at all. One question I think it works on though is the youtube downloader question. He doesn't want people to answer with a website/webapp.

Comment: Also to consider: is a "command-line tool" considered a "desktop-client"? And: doesn't "client" imply there's a "server" component involved somehow?